# Using getAppender() in Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, appender

I wrote a custom appender `JTableAppender` which implements `ILoggingEvent`. This appender has a public setter `setModel(..)` to assign a table model to the appender, so I can manipulate the model in `doAppend()`.

The JTableAppender is configurated in an xml file, where I named it TABLE:

```
<appender name="TABLE" class="blabla.jgwf.test.logger.JTableAppender">
    <!-- encoders are by default assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder> 
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

To be able to use the setter from the outside, I tried to get the appender using

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("blabal");
JTableAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = (JTableAppender<ILoggingEvent>)logger.getAppender("TABLE");
```

When I tried to set a model using

```
appender.setModel(...);
```

I got a NullPointerException for exactly this line. The getAppender() didn't work as I wish it would.

Comment: To which logger is the appender attached to? You should call getAppender on that logger.

Comment: show me the setup of your logger. Looks like you have not add your Appender to your logger, so the `logger.getAppender("TABLE")` returns `null`.

Comment: ok thank you guys for the hint. i forgot to mention the appender in the configuration file.

Comment: <logger name="blabla.jgwf.test.gui" level="TRACE" >
 <appender-ref ref="TABLE" /> // works after added this line.
    </logger>

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**: Use Logger.getRootLogger() instead your local variable 'logger'.

(*example*)

```
SMTPAppender emailAppender = 
(SMTPAppender)Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("SMTPAppender");
```

doing this, you wont get NullException, and to **APPLY** changes on your appender then you have to write this: `emailAppender.activateOptions();`

Answer (score 1):

using logback 1.1.3 I had to:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory    
...
val root: Logger = val root: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).asInstanceOf[Logger]
val myAppender = root.getAppender("MyAppenderName")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the Java version to [Todor Kolev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238044/todor-kolev)'s Scala answer:

```
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    // appender name, as configured in logback.xml: <appender name="CLI" class="...
    Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = root.getAppender("CLI");
    CliLogAppender cliLogAppender = (CliLogAppender) appender;
    System.out.println("> " + cliLogAppender.someCustomMethod());
```

The example contains the fully qualified package names to avoid confusion between slf4j and logback.

I defined the adapter named `CLI` in logback.xml. Logback then creates the instance and sends the logs to it. As shown above, this way you can get a handle of the instance and work with the logging data.

Be careful with this, as adding it to a library will break logging, if the client code doesn't use logback! Think: use just for your own code (or with proper guarding code around it).

(And make sure your appenders logging datastructure discards old logs automatically, in case you "forget" to handle and pruge the data properly).