# Changing appends programmatically

Tags: scala, logging, log4j, logback

I want to get an appender and apply it to different loggers. I have an appender defined in my "logback.xml". Is there a way to get this appender, change the file location and apply to a logger.

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logg.log</file>
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

This is how I am adding a new FileAppender and applying to a specific logger. I need a way to do this for an existing appender.

```
    val fileAppender = new FileAppender()
    fileAppender.setFile("/location/logg.log")
    val roote = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FOO.Class")
    roote.addAppender(fileAppender)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do this (note - untested):

```
val roote = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FOO.Class")
val appender = roote.getAppender("APPENDER_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_GET")
roote.addAppender(appender)
```

See: [Using getAppender() in Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471202/using-getappender-in-logback)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help , Yes this will work but i need to change the file location for the appender and then apply to the logger. Is it possible to do something like 

       appender.setFile("my new location ") 

and then apply it to the logger.